# How to replace a substring between two indices

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace text between two indices in Javascript, something like:

```
str = "The Hello World Code!";
str.replaceBetween(4,9,"Hi");
// outputs "The Hi World Code"
```

The indices and the string are both dynamic.

How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

There is no such method in JavaScript. But you can always create your own:

```js
String.prototype.replaceBetween = function(start, end, what) {
  return this.substring(0, start) + what + this.substring(end);
};

console.log("The Hello World Code!".replaceBetween(4, 9, "Hi"));
```

Comment: @Exception OTOH, the chance of namespace collision is negligible with this method name ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak But I have concern about reference created every time when a string object is created. I feel it would be completely safe if it is added to a separate namespace as utility method. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Exception reference of what? Function references are cheap, and only one will be created. The function won't be cloned, or even a reference to it. I don't think that extending `String.prototype` will cause creation of non-primitive String objects in the javascript engine internally either.

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer is correct, but I wanted to avoid extending the String `prototype`:

```
function replaceBetween(origin, startIndex, endIndex, insertion) {
  return origin.substring(0, startIndex) + insertion + origin.substring(endIndex);
}
```

Usage:

```
replaceBetween('Hi World', 3, 7, 'People');

// Hi People
```

If using a concise arrow function, then it's:

```
const replaceBetween = (origin, startIndex, endIndex, insertion) =>
  origin.substring(0, startIndex) + insertion + origin.substring(endIndex);
```

If using template literals, then it's:

```
const replaceBetween = (origin, startIndex, endIndex, insertion) =>
  `${origin.substring(0, startIndex)}${insertion}${origin.substring(endIndex)}`;
```

Answer (score 8):

There is an [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method in JavaScript which does this job, but no `String.splice`. If you convert your string into an array, however:

```
var str = "The Hello World Code!";
var arr = str.split('');
var removed = arr.splice(4,5,"Hi"); // arr is modified
str = arr.join('');
```

Comment: Note that while it is possible to call `Array.splice` on a string, it won't act as desired because strings are immutable.

Comment: He is not using `splice` on a string. He is creating a new array containing all of the individual characters by calling `split('')`, then relying upon the side effects of using `splice` on that array (removing characters from the array), and finally stitching it back together into a new string by calling `join('')`. I would argue that this is a very intuitive answer for people familiar with the methods being used. But it is not the shortest or the most efficient.

Comment: I understand this post has been a while. Currently `split` and `join` do not work nicely with many emoji (such as )

Answer (score 2):

This is how it worked for me.

```
var str = "The Hello World Code!";
var newStr="Hi"

var startIndex= 4;  // start index of 'H' from 'Hello'
var endIndex= 8; // end index of 'o' from 'Hello'
var preStr = str.substring(0, startIndex);
var postStr = str.substring(endIndex+1, str.length - 1);
var result = preStr+newStr+postStr;);     // outputs "The Hi World Code"
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ujvus6po/1/

Answer (score 0):

Another approach when you need to totally replace a string at a specific index, with quite the same function call with `String.prototype.replace` could be this:

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, fromString, toString) {
    let hasWrongParams = typeof index !== 'number'
                || !fromString || typeof fromString !== 'string'
                || !toString || typeof toString !== 'string';
    if(hasWrongParams) return '';
    let fromIndex = index;
    let toIndex = index + fromString.length;
    return this.substr(0, fromIndex) + toString + this.substr(toIndex);
}
```

https://gist.github.com/kwnccc/9df8554474e39f4b17a07efbbdf7971c

For example:

```
let string = 'This is amazing world, it's still amazing!';
string.replaceAt(8, 'amazing', 'worderful');
// 'This is worderful world, it's still amazing!'
string.replaceAt(34, 'amazing', 'worderful');
// 'This is amazing world, it's still worderful!'
```

Answer (score 0):

A more robust version of [VisioN's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14880260/6798201) solution that detects out of range errors and throws meaningful and easy to debug `RangeError`s. If you want, you can extend the `String.prototype` as well.

```js
function replaceString(str, start, end, replace) {
  if (start < 0 || start > str.length) {
    throw new RangeError(`start index ${start} is out of the range 0~${str.length}`);
  }
  if (end > str.length || end < start) {
    throw new RangeError(`end index ${end} is out of the range ${start}~${str.length}`);
  }
  return str.substring(0, start) + replace + str.substring(end);
}

// replace in the middle of the string, replacement string can be any length
console.log(replaceString("abcdef", 2, 4, "hhhh")); // output: "abhhhhef"

// insert in the front of the string, start and end index equal to 0
console.log(replaceString("abcdef", 0, 0, "hhhh")); // output: "hhhhabcdef"

// append at the end of the string, start and end index equal to the length of the string
console.log(replaceString("abcdef", 6, 6, "hhhh")); // output: "abcdefhhhh"

// error 1: start index is greater than end index
// console.log(replaceString("abcdef", 4, 2, "hhhh")); // output: RangeError: end index 2 is out of the range 4~6

// error 2: start/end index is less than 0
// console.log(replaceString("abcdef", -2, 2, "hhhh")); // output: RangeError: start index -2 is out of the range 0~6

// error 3: start/end index is greater than length of the string
// console.log(replaceString("abcdef", 3, 20, "hhhh")); // output: RangeError: end index 20 is out of the range 3~6
```