# Split string and keep the deliminter

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to split a string like this:  "abcde${variable}zzz"

I want to split the string so I can replace the variable with a value.  I don't know ahead of time what the variable name will be so that's why I was trying to avoid using "replace".

Comment: And what's the point of avoiding using `replace`, may I ask?

Comment: @Raina, I want to check first if the variable specified in the string really exists first. This string is coming from a configuration file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather trivial when you actually deal with *property* of some predefined object (containing all the data). For example:

```
var data = {
  foo: 'FOOFOO',
  bar: 'BARBAR'
};
var tplFoo = "abcde${foo}fghz";
var tplBar = "abcde${bar}fghz";
var tplBaz = "abcde${baz}fghz";
[tplFoo, tplBar, tplBaz].forEach(function(tpl) {
  console.log(
    tpl.replace(/\$\{([^}]+)}/g, function(match, gr) {
      return gr in data ? data[gr] : match;
    })
  );
});

// ... this gives you:
// abcdeFOOFOOfghz
// abcdeBARBARfghz
// abcde${baz}fghz
```

That's more or less how templating functions work. You can do the same trick with global variables (as they can be accessed via global object). For example:

```
// on the global level
var foo = 'FOOFOO';
var bar = 'BARBAR';
...
tpl.replace(/\$\{([^}]+)}/g, function(match, gr) {
  return gr in window ? window[gr] : match;
})
```

It's even possible to do with locals, but you'll have to use `eval` here:

```
(function(){
  var foo = 'FOOFOO';
  var bar = 'BARBAR';

  var tplFoo = "abcde${foo}fgh${foo}z";
  var tplBar = "abcde${bar}fghz";
  var tplBaz = "abcde${baz}fghz";
  [tplFoo, tplBar, tplBaz].forEach(function(tpl) {
    console.log(
      tpl.replace(/\$\{([^}]+)}/g, function(match, gr) {
        'use strict';
        try {
          var v = eval(gr);
          return v;
        }
        catch(_) { 
          return match; 
        }
      })
    );
  });
})();
```

... which, even in this simple case, may lead to very... unneeded consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var str = "abcde${variable}zzz"
var key = str.match(/\$\{.*\}/g);
var listOfelements = str.split(key[0]);
```

If you have more than one variable you may need to do something extra

Answer (score 0):

```
var config = {
    'foo': 'abc'
};

var str = 'foo: ${foo} bar: ${bar}';

var matches = str.match(/(\$\{\w+\})/g);

if(matches !== null) {
    for(var i=0,l=matches.length;i<l;i++) {
        var token = matches[i];
        var tvar = token.substr(2,token.length-3);

        if(tvar in config) {
            str = str.replace(token,config[tvar]);
        }
        else {
            str = str.replace(token,'null');
        }
    }
}

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Why go over string with `match` first, when you eventually still do `replace`, I wonder? It all can be done in a single approach, supplying callback param into `replace` function.

Comment: I made it clear so that he could do things with the results before doing the replace. Obviously this method is primitive in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var x = "abcde${variable}zzz";
alert(x.replace(/{.*}/, 'new_word'));
```

Or if you want it to do with index I found an answer in SO itself .. here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880229/how-to-replace-a-substring-between-two-indices)