# Multiple sequential string replacement between two indices

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, replace

I have a long string **'str'** and a list of a triplets in the form **[start, end, replace_str]**. I need to iterate through the list of triplets and replace the contents of **'str'** between start and end indices by replace_str. The replace_str string can be of variable length. The problem is that after the first triplet replacement, the content and length of 'str' gets changed and the replacement by next triplet's start and end indices do not remain valid and replacement happens at wrong position.

e.g. If

```
str = 'I want to go to India.'
```

and the list of triplets is

```
[3,7,'<span id="7">want</span>']

[11,13,'<span id="49">go</span>']

[1,2,'<span id="1003">I</span>']
```

After the replacement with first triplet, 'str' looks like:

```
'I <span id="7">want</span> to go to India'.
```

Now for second triplet replacement with **start = 11** and **end = 13**, the str will look like:

```
'I <span id<span id="49">go<span>>7">want</span> to go to India.'
```

whereas I want it to look like

```
'I <span id="7">want</span> to <span id="49">go<span> to India.'
```

How do I handle such multiple sequential string replacements in javascript ?

**EDIT:** https://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/david-thomas suggested that my original question above is a XY problem - a problem with solution for another problem and not the actual problem. So here goes the actual problem.

Starting with :

```
str = 'I want to go to India.'
```

and the list of triplets is

```
[3,7,'<span id="7">want</span>']

[11,13,'<span id="49">go</span>']

[1,2,'<span id="1003">I</span>']
```

I want to replace the contents of **str** between **start** and **end** with **replace_str** so that my result string, after replacement of all triplets, will look like this :

```
'<span id="1003">I<span> <span id="7">want</span> to <span id="49">go<span> to India.'
```

Comment: I think this is a problem with the attempted solution of another problem - otherwise known as an "[XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)." Can you tell, or show, us what the original problem was, because this solution *feels* over-complicated.

Comment: I have provided description of actual problem above in the edit.

Comment: Looking at the (presumably simplified) input/output this seems to be a question about how to wrap certain words with an element of a specific `id`? Should *all* instances of the supplied words (`'want'`, `'go'` and `'I'`), if they occurred more than once, be replaced, or only those at the specific (initial) indices?

Comment: Yes. The problem is to wrap certain substrings of str with specific id. And it needs to happen once only for specified indices.

Comment: To follow on from the questions of @DavidThomas: What is the context in which you need to solve this problem? What do the different span `id`s represent? Will every sentence that contains "I" have this word wrapped in a `<span id="1003">`? Will all pronouns be wrapped in a `<span id="1003">`? Or all words of only one letter? Do you gave just one "long string 'str'" to treat, or do you have many similar strings? Can you give examples? Are the `id`s that you use the same for the same words in each string? Perhaps there is a more generic solution that could treat this problem efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the replacement triplets never overlap, then you can start at the end and work back towards the beginning:

```
String.prototype.replaceBetween = function(start, end, what) {
    return this.substring(0, start) + what + this.substring(end);
};

var str = 'I want to go to India.'
var triplets = [
  [3,7,'<span id="7">want</span>']
, [11,13,'<span id="49">go</span>']
, [1,2,'<span id="1003">I</span>']
]

triplets.sort(function (a, b) {
  return b[0] - a[0]
})

for (var ii=0, triplet; triplet=triplets[ii]; ii++) {
  str = str.replaceBetween(triplet[0]-1, triplet[1], triplet[2])
}

console.log(str)
// <span id="1003">I</span><span id="7">want</span>to <span id="49">go</span>to India.
```

You can find the original post about the `replaceBetween()` technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14880260/1927589).

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to worry about shifting indices when you replace strings that occur later in the original string first. To do this, you could sort the list of replacements by their start indices in reverse order:

```
function mreplace(str, repl) {
    repl.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a[0] < b[0]) return 1;
        if (a[1] > b[1]) return -1;
        return 0;
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < repl.length; i++) {
        var begin = repl[i][0];
        var end = repl[i][1];
        var s = repl[i][2];

        str = str.substr(0, begin) + s + str.substr(end);
    }

    return str;
}

var str = mreplace("I want to go to India", [
    [2, 6, '<span id="7">want</span>'],
    [10, 12, '<span id="49">go</span>'],
    [0, 1, '<span id="1003">I</span>']
]);

console.log(str);

// "<span id="1003">I</span> <span id="7">want</span> to <span id="49">go</span> to India"
```

This snippet can have unpredictable results when two or more starting indices are the same. because Javascript's sorting algorithm isn't necessarily stable, you must find other means of ensuring a defined replacement order. (You could make the sort stable by pushing the original list index to each triplet and use that as secondary sorting criterion.)

Note that I have changed the start and end indices in your example, so that they are zero-based, which is how indices in Javascript work. In my opinion, deviating from this index representation creates a lot of confusion.