# How to make a clickable value to enter a textbox use javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

`How do i make bbcode to enter a text box eg:
like this [javascript to allow click image to input value like this Click For Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOGZi.png)

I use this code to my understanding but did not work

```
<h2>BB Code And Smiley</h2><input type="text" id="f1" value="[a] [/a]"/>
<input type="image" id="f2" value="[b] [/b]" on click="document.getElementById('f2').value = document.getElementById('f1'). value+="document.getElementById('f1').value"><img src="bold.png"/></input><b r/>
<input type="text" id="f1" name="mess" value="'.htmlentities($_POST['mess']).'"/><br/>
<script>
```

`

Comment: Can you post an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: php is not working without opening tags, and there in your example closing tags are also required. html attribute "on click" not exists, you mean "onClick"?. value of an input element cant be written like you did. [a][/a] wtf? your javascript code into on click attribute is totally wrong

Comment: yes am poor in js i need assistance on this ple-ase assist me thanks

Comment: would be happy if you can assist me with what i mean i want if they click image like B,I,BR to take element value of the onClick to a textarea/input box  assist me plea-se

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CheapApples12/a0wdeeqb/2/), otherwise; here's the source code:

```
<div id="editor">
  <ul id="buttons">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:bbcoder('B')">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:bbcoder('U')"><u>U</u></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:bbcoder('I')">I</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:bbcoder('Q')">""</a></li>
  </ul>
  <form id="editor-form" action="" method="post">
    <div>
      <textarea id="blog_body" name="blog_body" rows="15" cols="20" placeholder="Use editor buttons on selected text">This is a sample text, select some word and click on the links provided above to see the demo.</textarea>
    </div>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </p>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
function bbcoder(code) {
  try {
    var old = "";
    var textarea = document.getElementsByName("blog_body")[0];
    var value = textarea.value;
    var startPos = textarea.selectionStart;
    var endPos = textarea.selectionEnd;
    var selectedText = value.substring(startPos, endPos);

    switch (code) {
      case 'B':
        bbbold(textarea, value, startPos, endPos, selectedText);
        break;
      case 'U':
        bbunder(textarea, value, startPos, endPos, selectedText);
        break;
      case 'I':
        bbitalic(textarea, value, startPos, endPos, selectedText);
        break;
      case 'Q':
        bbquote(textarea, value, startPos, endPos, selectedText);
        break;
      default:
        alert('Invalid argument');
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e.toString());
  }

}

function bbbold(textarea, value, startPos, endPos, selectedText) {
  textarea.value = value.replaceBetween(startPos, endPos, "[b]" + selectedText + "[/b]");
}

function bbitalic(textarea, value, startPos, endPos, selectedText) {
  textarea.value = value.replaceBetween(startPos, endPos, "[i]" + selectedText + "[/i]");

}

function bbunder(textarea, value, startPos, endPos, selectedText) {
  textarea.value = value.replaceBetween(startPos, endPos, "[u]" + selectedText + "[/u]");
}

function bbquote(textarea, value, startPos, endPos, selectedText) {
  textarea.value = value.replaceBetween(startPos, endPos, "[quote]" + selectedText + "[/quote]");
}


//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880229/how-to-replace-a-substring-between-two-indices
String.prototype.replaceBetween = function(start, end, what) {
  return this.substring(0, start) + what + this.substring(end);
};
</script>
```

Comment: Good great job @ Bradley Hodges

I am so glad i think this the right thing i  need

Comment: Work fine but how can i use that for select/drop down value??? 

Assists me plea_se 

I am poor in javascript

Comment: Please any assists on how to add select/dropdown value with onclick to the above code???

Comment: Sorry, I've been unwell for the last 2 days. I have no idea how you would run this code in a drop-down menu, other than extra javascript to define what a click action is. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5323626/4365209