# String replace between two given indexes in multiple places of the string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a string and an array of start and end indexes in the string which need to be replaced with some other content. For example, the input string is like follows:

`Mention 1, Mention 3 and no more mentions.`

And the array of indexes to be replaced is as follows:

```
[
  {
     start: 0,
     end: 8
  },
  {
     start: 11;
     end: 18
  }
]
```

Basically this should result in a string where the `Mention 1` and `Mention 3` are wrapped in an anchor (link).

I have found some examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880229/how-to-replace-a-substring-between-two-indices) one:

```
String.prototype.replaceBetween = function(start, end, what) {
  return this.substring(0, start) + what + this.substring(end);
};

console.log("The Hello World Code!".replaceBetween(4, 9, "Hi"));
```

However the problem with this implementation is that it's good only if there's 1 only place to replace, in my case there can be multiple places to be replaced. After the first replace the indexes for the rest will be shifted as the string will now contain also .

Any hint/clue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Another option would be to adjust all subsequent indices after replacing for each set.

Comment: As I read this, you don't want to actually _replace_ the mentions, you want to _wrap_ them, so `Mention 3` becomes `<a href="...">Mention 3</a>` retaining the text — is that correct?

Comment: Extending the built-in objects of JavaScript used to be a common practice but is found unfavorable. You always have the ever so slight chance that a browser vendor might create it's own `String.prototype.replaceBetween` and thus breaking your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: There are 2 questions here, as your example doesn't really cover the wrapping.

Using indexes, as you mention, each replacement shifts the position of all elements **after** the replacement. However, the indexes of characters **before** it would remain unchanged. You would simply need to iterate them in reverse.

```js
var str = 'Mention 1, Mention 3 and no more mentions.'
for (const { start, end } of positions.reverse()) {
  str = str.replaceBetween(start, end, 'REPLACEMENT')
}
```

This doesn't really address the wrapping concern, though. If you actually must use array indices, the above could be changed to accept a function, e.g.:

```js
String.prototype.replaceBetween = function (start, end, replacer) {
  const what = replacer(this.substring(start, end));
  return this.substring(0, start) + what + this.substring(end);
};

for (const { start, end } of positions.reverse()) {
  str = str.replaceBetween(start, end, (match) => `<a href="#">${match}</a>`);
}
```

If the indexes array is just an artifact of searching for a particular pattern, though, a cleaner solution could leverage `String#replace` with a regex and a replacer function

```js
// the `/g` at the end means "global", so it will replace all matches
const pattern = /Mention \d+/g;

var str = 'Mention 1, Mention 3 and no more mentions.'
str = str.replace(/Mention \d+/g, (match) => {
  return `<a href="#">${match}</a>`;
});
```

Output: `'<a href="#">Mention 1</a>, <a href="#">Mention 3</a> and no more mentions.'`

Answer (score 1):

You must loop over your position array. Like that:

```js
const n = [
  {
     start: 0,
     end: 8
  },
  {
     start: 11,
     end: 18
  }
];

let str = 'Mention 1, Mention 3 and no more mentions.';

String.prototype.replaceBetween = function(start, end, what) {
  return this.substring(0, start) + what + this.substring(end);
};

n.forEach(e => {  
  console.log("The Hello World Code!".replaceBetween(e.start, e.end, "Hi"));  
})
```